# Featured products on mezzanine project homepage

Tags: python, django, django-views, mezzanine, cartridge

I am working on an implementation of an online shop using cartridge & mezzanine.
I would like to include a "featured products" section using a category from cartridge's shop (product_category). I have created a test category, populated it with entries and am trying to view it from the homepage but it doesn't return anything. What should i be doing instead?

*index.html*

```
{% with category as "featured" %}
{% for product in products.object_list %}
```

(just using the category.html product display html for now)

*views.py*

```
def index(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'products': products}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code in index.html:

> {% with category as "featured" %}

means treat variable `category` as string literals (are you sure that this is what you want?), so you will unable to use variable `featured` after this statement.

> Values enclosed in single quotes (') or double quotes (") are treated as
>   string literals, while values without quotes are treated as template 
>   variables. (Django docs)

Next, according to your code, you have `products` variable (and this is QuerySet) in your context, so value products.object_list will give nothing, as a QuerySet object do not have `object_list` attribute.
Maybe what you want in this line is

`{% for product in products %}`

You may publish more code to clarify situation.